# Ошибка при определении типа (P in)

Tags: javascript, typescript

TypeScript. Ниже пример. Ошибка подчеркнута в комментарии.

```
type foo = {
  stringProp: string
}

type bar = {
  [p in ('a' | 'b')]: number
}

// Надо привести к такому
type union = {
  stringProp: string
  a: number
  b: number
}

// Работает
type union1 = foo & bar

// Работает
type union2 = foo & {
  [p in ('a' | 'b')]: number
}

// Работает
type union3 = bar & {
  stringProp: string
}

// !!! Не работает
type fooBar = {
  stringProp: string
  [p in ('a' | 'b')]: number
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ------------------- Error
}

// В то же время - это работает
type fooBarSuccess = {
  stringProp: string
  [i: number]: number
}
```

Не вижу разницы каким образом объединить тип. Но почему там ошибка?
Ссылка на [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#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)

**Update:**

Нашел эту ошибку в документации [mapped-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) *(чуть ниже проскроллить надо)*.
Ссылка на их же пример [This is an error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=4&pln=7&pc=20#code/PTAEAEFMCdoe2gZwFygEwDYCcBmUBGABkIFYD80AOAKBFAFVFJQAXACwEsVqWBPAB2YAFAIbQWHEQBsA6h3YA5SAHcAspAC2AIxgAeACoA+UAF5QAb2qhQAbSGgOAO1ABrSLzgAzUPoC6AflR9O18AbmoAX1AAMgtQRxV1bRhULTg4KUgRZwjqWjB9TkQHYuzQGHhoAEIeAWYZeEcAc1FxSVl5NiU1TR1oA2MzS2s7B2c3D28-QJ8Q8OsEnuToVPTM7PCIoA).
Но человекоПонятного объяснения там нет.

Comment: скорее всего это связано с тем, что в этом случае путаются mapped типы и обычные типы и компилятор не может разобрать где что использовать.

Comment: Можно сказать, что тип можно объявить двумя способами, имеется ввиду с помощью литерала `{...}`: перечислить поля или построить на основе другого типа и эти два способа не пересекаются ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy Да, видимо так и есть. Как то особо TypeScript относится к эти вычисляемым свойствам и никуда не хочет их впихивать, только раздельное определение с последующим слиянием.

Comment: Не не, это же НЕ вычисляемое свойство, это именно map одного типа на другой. Там могут быть достаточно сложные условия, поэтому скорее всего сложно разбирать из, если бы еще можно было и просто свойства задавать

Comment: @Grundy ^) да, да. Просто ошибка начинается с `A computed property name...`, вот у меня за время исследований и въелась в голову такая формулировка.

Comment: скорее всего ту имелся ввиду другой смысл :) типа вычисляются свойства для нового типа :) хотя так тоже не очень формулировка :)

Comment: ts(1170) имеет такой же текст ошибки как и ts(1169) - просто скопипастили да забыли поменять, не?) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA1hIGcoF4oHICGaoB90CM0AoI0SKAIRSgG8iooFgAnASwDsBzABWYHswALkYsOnelAD0AKmkSo0qAEEoAYz4BbMAFdgEACZQw-SM1BR2GDdA5QMUMtAA2rPcwxOoG7UyjMIAGYQzPKKwHx27FAQAB7GEAgIrHxRAO4AFnwI0I5QrEj2Lm4eDuDQfMx26NrsrACO2tAIIBr4fE7YjgB0ABQAjH0A7AAMAJShkhIA2mB5UXCIALrC7NqtwVKSAyNEAL5EHG4BGKrQAMK0EjJyDArKapo6eobGAsHmltZzkXNHJ9DeXz+IKVUIOCIYKKxeKJZJpTLZUrkfJVIrBEq5CpVNA1eqNRgtNodJEQXoDABsAE5xrdpJMGDNvgsEMsLGt8BtJFs+lS9kQgA